# How to update item position after drag and drop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I got problem with update position after i drag item. So i have array object:

```
  [
    {id: 1, name: "AAA", position:1},
    {id: 2, name: "BBB", position:2}, 
    {id: 3, name: "CCC", position:3},
    {id: 4, name: "DDD", position:4}
  ]
```

then i want to move item 3 to top become to:

```
[
  {id: 3, name: "CCC", position:3},
  {id: 1, name: "AAA", position:1},
  {id: 2, name: "BBB", position:2}, 
  {id: 4, name: "DDD", position:4}
]
```

So how can i update array like this:

```
[
  {id: 3, name: "CCC", position:1},
  {id: 1, name: "AAA", position:2},
  {id: 2, name: "BBB", position:3}, 
  {id: 4, name: "DDD", position:4}
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use simple `forEach` condition.And update the position value with array 
 increment

```js
var ar = [
  {id: 3, name: "CCC", position:3},
  {id: 1, name: "AAA", position:1},
  {id: 2, name: "BBB", position:2}, 
  {id: 4, name: "DDD", position:4}
]
console.log(update_position(ar))

function update_position(arr){
arr.forEach(function(a,b){
 a.position=b+1;
})
return arr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ar = [
  {id: 3, name: "CCC", position:3},
  {id: 1, name: "AAA", position:1},
  {id: 2, name: "BBB", position:2}, 
  {id: 4, name: "DDD", position:4}
]
console.log(update_position(ar))

function update_position(arr){
arr.forEach(function(a,b){
 a.position=b+1;
})
return arr
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it's not the right way of usage .if you get the correct answer mark as a answer in left side green [mark of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). not copying the answer post as your self. better take [a tour of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)